# How can i optimize this code?

Tags: c#, optimization, methods

I have this following code:

```
    if (userValueSom01 == realResult01)
    {
        //answer = correct
        //count +1 for overall good answers
        WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.totallGood++;
        //count for good +1
        answerThisWindowGood++;
        //make visible the green logo
        Som01G.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        //answer = wrong
        //count +1 for overall wrong answers
        WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.totallWrong++;
        //count for wrong +1
        answerThisWindowWrong++;
        //make visible the red logo
        Som01W.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        labelSom01Check.Content = Convert.ToString(realResult01);
    }
```

Now the point is, this happens XX times, where XX is a number corresponding with the numbers you see within the code.
So in the above example the XX is 01.
 *note, its the 01's in the input, and the 01 in the results too

In not very deep into c# (yet), and at first i thought that when XX is 20, i will need to copy this above part 20 times, and change the numbers.
Now this seems cumbersome, and i guess there should be some smarter way ti deal with this, point is, i cant think of how (as written above, im not very deep into c# yet).

Anyone that can push me into the right direction ?

thank you in advance.

---EDIT 1---
thank you Miika L.
slightly different from your solution:

```
public bool checkValue(double value, int result, Image controlG, Image controlW, Label label)
        {
            if (value == result)
            {
                //... Do stuff
                controlG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //... Do other stuff
                controlW.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                label.Content = result.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and now i can indeed just call:
bool test = checkValue(userValueSom01, realResult01, Som01G, Som01W, labelSom01Check);

works :)
thanx!

Comment: From above code, not much optimization can be done. How about you repeat xx times (record in one counter), then setup value (by the counter)

Comment: ahaa, so with a repeat and make the values ++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about writing it as a function?

```
public bool checkValue(
    int value,
    int result,
    Control controlG,
    Control controlW,
    Label label)
{
    if (value == result)
    {
        ... Do stuff
        controlG.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        ... Do other stuff
        controlW.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        label.Content = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahaa and then just call it 1 by 1 but it will only take 1 line right ? that already makes more sense then to paste the whole thing xx times. And i guess i can make this into a other class so i can easy call it at different spots too :)

Comment: Protip: A method called `CheckXXX` should not mutate data or alter state.

Comment: Uuh, wasnt its so, that it is possible using the "ref" key ? or am i now totally mixing up stuff? (i need to re-read on that chapter i guess hehe)

Comment: The controls are reference types, so are automatically passed by reference. The "ref" keyword shouldn't be necessary, I think?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining hundreds of variables with numbers in its name like userValueSom01, realResult01 better use an **Array** or a **Dictionary** if apropriate.

Comment: Dont know Dictionary (yet), will look into that